# PHP restructuring data result from sql table

Tags: php, sql

I have the following SQL table:

Salespeople

| uid | Salesperson | Sold | Date Sold | Price | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jimmy | Lemonade | 2020-01-02 | 12 | 4 |
| 1 | Jimmy | Lemonade | 2020-01-02 | 12 | 4 |
| 2 | Terrence | Gym Equipment | 2020-01-03 | 34 | 6 |
| 3 | Jimmy | Lemonade | 2020-01-04 | 15 | 3 |
| 3 | Jimmy | Gym Equipment | 2020-01-04 | 20 | 9 |

I am wanting to break down this table into a multidimensional PHP array that is arranged in hierarchy of:

```
->each salesperson
-->all dates on the table (from 2020-01-02 thru 2020-01-04) per salesperson
--->items sold per salesperson on the date (blank array if nothing sold on that date)
--->quantity sold per salesperson at each rate
```

So to visualize the result, it would look more like the table below:

| Salesperson | Sold | Price | 2020-01-02 | 2020-01-03 | 2020-01-04 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jimmy | Lemonade | 12 | Qty: 8 | Qty: 0 | Qty: 0 |
| Jimmy | Lemonade | 15 | Qty: 3 | Qty: 0 | Qty: 3 |
| Jimmy | Gym Equipment | 20 | Qty: 0 | Qty: 0 | Qty: 9 |
| Terrence | Gym Equipment | 34 | Qty: 0 | Qty: 6 | Qty: 0 |

I am having a mental block and the full logic isn't quite coming to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the data by salesperson, date sold, and sold items, and then use PHP to create a multidimensional array from the result. Use this SQL query

```
SELECT Salesperson, Sold, Price, Date_Sold, SUM(Qty) as Qty
FROM Salespeople
GROUP BY Salesperson, Sold, Price, Date_Sold
ORDER BY Salesperson, Date_Sold, Sold
```

Then this PHP script

```
// Execute the SQL query and fetch the result into $result variable
$result = // execute the above SQL query

// Initialize an empty array to store the result
$sales = array();

// Loop through each row of the SQL result
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    // Extract the values from the current row
    $salesperson = $row['Salesperson'];
    $sold = $row['Sold'];
    $price = $row['Price'];
    $date_sold = $row['Date_Sold'];
    $qty = $row['Qty'];

    // Add the values to the multidimensional array
    $sales[$salesperson][$date_sold][$sold] = array(
        'price' => $price,
        'qty' => $qty
    );
}

// Print the resulting multidimensional array
print_r($sales);
```